# Why doesn’t classical atomic exist?

Tags: atomic-chess

Every player rated over 1700 pretty much flat out refuses to play slow games of atomic chess. I understand that it has something to do with white’s first move advantage, but still, there’s no community whatsoever.

There’s around 10,000 active players on lichess and not one wants to play a game longer than 5 minutes. When I take my time during 5+3 games I’ve had players resign and switch to bullet.

I’ve long yearned for quality games of atomic chess but I seem doomed to consume vapid pre move garbage like the rest of us.

Comment: Hi, I would like to counter that there do exist some people on lichess who play slower games, though it is not as popular of a format as it can be quite boring and hard to calculate deeply in atomic. I am around 1960 rated in atomic on lichess myself, and I love to play 5+0, 5+3 and 10+0 games and even play some correspondence atomic games as well. Believe it or not, there are some people out there who don't like to play atomic bullet because it is just too fast paced, including me. I can't move fast enough to last in a bullet game and afraid to lose my rating points.

Comment: Is this question not better directed to the Chess platform that actually provides the game?

In addition, think of your question like this.... "why isn't everyone driving 3 wheel motorcycles. I really enjoy 3 wheel motor cycles, there 10k registered globally, but i cant seem to convince anyone else to ride a 3 wheeled motorcycle."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be a number of reasons for this; however this question is going to continually struggle to get Non-Opinion based answers based off the nature of the question.

**Viewability:**

Like most sports and games, variants aren't predominately successful as there has to be an entire new set of rules to follow. New level or understandings, the requirement to develop an entire market, build a fan base.

**Technical Interest:**

If a person has dedicated 10 hours a week for the past 15 years, variants aren't usually that interesting other than as a novel exercise. In most instances chess variants though very similar aren't as technically engaging (at least in my opinion and anecdotal experience of other FM to GM players).

**Ability to determine a exact path:**

The biggest problem is probably here. There are chess variants that have effectively been Brute Forced, and solved. At which point, it is Vaudeville.